# mysql query question on count

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT if((COUNT(vote=1)-COUNT(vote=0) > 0,1,count(groupid))
FROM sample WHERE uid = $uid GROUP BY groupid
```

In the if statement, I was wondering if there is any simple way to achieve this: COUNT(vote=1)-COUNT(vote=0) > 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUM instead of COUNT:

```
SELECT if((SUM(vote=1)-SUM(vote=0) > 0,1,count(groupid))
FROM sample WHERE uid = $uid GROUP BY groupid
```

Comment: You can also use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(groupid)`.

Comment: And you **should** use `COALESCE(SUM(..),0)` instead of `SUM(..)` for the cases that there are no rows with `..` and `SUM(..)` returns `NULL`.

Comment: is there any reason why i should use sum instead of count? vote = 0 means sum of it will be 0. so there is no point of doing sum.

Answer (score 1):

You want the sum of `vote`, except `0` counts as `-1`:

```
SELECT if(sum(if(vote, 1, -1)) > 0, 1, count(groupid))
...
```

Comment: Nice. (assuming that `vote` takes only two values: `0` or `1`.)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to do

```
Select columns, 
case when (COUNT(vote=1) - COUNT(vote=0)) > 0
then 'something'
else 'something else' as foo
From Sample
Where uid=$uid
Group By groupid
```

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. 
With my example, you select the columns (or just that case), when the difference is greater than 0. If it is greater show 'something' else show 'something else'

although, i don't have a way to test it on this computer, but maybe it will lead you or someone else in the right direction.